# C programming - Output result in decimals

Tags: c

At the momemt, i'm learning the C and the basics of the language, but I have a problem with my code. When I multiply two numbers, I cant get the decimals, even I float the numbers I enter.

My code:

```
int main()
{
    double result_met, km;

    result_met = km = 0.0f;

    /*Display text*/
    printf("Enter values of the distance between the two cities in km's\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &km);

    /*Formular for a simple km conversion*/
    result_met = km * 1000.0f;

    /*Result print*/
    printf("Meter:%d", result_met);

    printf("\nWaiting for a character to be pressed from the keyboard to exit.\n");

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format specifiers are incorrect - it should be `%lf` - `%d` is for `int`.

```
scanf_s("%lf", &km);

/*Formular for a simple km conversion*/
result_met = km * 1000.0f;

/*Result print*/
printf("Meter:%lf", result_met);
```

[Format string specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications)

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier for double is `%lf`, not `%d`
You may as well use a `float` instead of a `double`, it saves memory (which is important when you begin to write big programs), then you must use the format specifier `%f` (the "l" in `%lf` is for "long", because a `double` is a `long float`)

When treating decimals, you want to print only a few decimals on the screen (to avoid the printing of a "2.50000001"), then you can use the format specifier `%.3f` if you want 3 and only 3 digits printed (`3` can be any integer).

for example, the following code :

```
printf("%.2f\n",3.1415);
```

has the following output :

```
3.14
```

the `printf` function has many different format specifier, that can be very useful.
Go see the [cpluplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) if you want to learn more about it

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to understand the principles. :-)